# QTableView selected element in PyQt4

Tags: qt, pyqt4, qtableview

Is there some way to read which row of Qt's `QTableView` widget is selected by user? Does it have something to do with `QModelIndex` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `QTableView::selectionModel()` (an inherited function from `QAbstractItemView`) which returns you a `QItemSelectionModel`. You then can call `QItemSelectionModel::selectedIndexes()`, which returns a list of `QModelIndex`es.

For reference, see [`QAbstractItemView::selectionModel()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel).